# Remove lines from CSV file that matches lines from another file from bash?

Tags: awk, sed, command-line, terminal

I have a (large) CSV file (A) that has this structure:

```
1234ABC 456789
1235ABD 098732
1235ABE 098731
1235ABF 198731
```

Another file (B) contains entries that should be removed from A:

```
1234ABC
1235ABE
```

I want to run a `awk` or `sed` command (or some command-line script if `awk` or `sed` are not sufficient) that removes all lines from A whose first column is equal to a line in B. I.e. the result in A after the script has run should be:

```
1235ABD 098732
1235ABF 198731
```

Note that it's not enough to simply remove a line in A that *starts with* any of the lines in B. For example, if A contains:

```
1235AC 456789
1235A 098732
```

and B contains:

```
1235A
```

then A should contain this afterwards:

```
1235AC 456789
```

How can I achieve this in bash, preferably using `awk` or `sed` (or a shell script if required)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'NR == FNR {dels[$1]; next} !($1 in dels)' file2.csv file1.csv

1235ABD 098732
1235ABF 198731
```

This is standard 2 pass awk command that stores all lines of `file2` in first pass in an array `dels`.

In 2nd pass we just print lines from `file1` where `$1` doesn't exist in array `dels`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat fileA
1234ABC 456789
1235ABD 098732
1235ABE 098731
1235ABF 198731
1235AC 456789
1235A 098732

$ cat fileB
1234ABC
1235ABE
1235A
```

One `grep` idea using inverted word matches from file `fileB`:

```
$ grep -vwf fileB fileA
1235ABD 098732
1235ABF 198731
1235AC 456789
```

**NOTE:** this will apply the match across the entire line (ie, not just the first column) so likely won't be accurate if the entries from `fileB` can show up in columns 2-thru-N of `fileA`

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lane 'BEGIN { %exclude = map { chomp; { $_ => 1 } } `cat B`; } print if ! $exclude{ $F[0] };' A
```

Prints:

```
1235ABD 098732
1235ABF 198731
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace.

First the `BEGIN {...}` block is executed. The contents of file `B` are stored in a hash `%exclude`, with keys = lines of file `B`, and values = 1. `chomp` removes the terminal newline. Note that `B` is stored in memory, which may be a problem for large files and small RAM.
`-lane` : causes the script to loop over file `A`, line by line, storing the whitespace-delimited fields in the array `@F`. Then, `$F[0]` is the first column of each line in `A`.
`print if ! $exclude{ $F[0] };` : Print the line of `A` if the first field (`$F[0]`) is not found in `B` (= not in the hash `%exclude`).

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)